# extending partition to root in ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, root, lvm

I'm working on a Ubuntu 22.04 VM of 300GB , I got a warning " / is using 95.0% of 97.87GB" , I tried to increase my hard-disk space by adding additional 300GB of harddisk.
This is the result for

```
df -h

tmpfs                              1.6G  1.3M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   93G     0 100% /
```

When I use the command `lsblk`, I'm able to find:

```
sda                         8:0    0   600G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   598G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
```

I tried to increase the size of my root using

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

But, I'm getting error,

```
resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
The filesystem is already 26214400 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Can someone help me, how to increase the size of my root. I tried to search for other options, but it asks me to use Gpart using GUI. but, I need solution using CLI.

Comment: The pv looks already resized, so you need to follow the steps to resize the lv before resizing the fs